# can I build swing applications on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I used to work on netbeans to build Java applications but now: i am using eclipse.
I was was wondering if there a a free good plug-in to help me with swing windows.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jigloo - CloudGarden](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/index.html)(free non-commercial)

[Visual Editor Project](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php)

AND [JForm](http://www.formdev.com/buy/) (pay)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a GUI designer. The best plug-in for this is the excellent [Swing Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/swingdesigner/index.html). Definitely worth a look.

Comment: Nope, sorry. But it is worth the license.

Answer (score 0):

[Jigloo](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/) is free for non-commercial use.  There are others on the [UI category](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewcatlink-cid-18.html) at [Eclipse Plugin Central](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[JForm](http://www.formdev.com/) designer is a good swing designer, but it is not free.